# How to move one object from one array to another on submit in React app

Tags: reactjs

I'm building a simple hotel reviews app in React. I had it set up to display the first 3 reviews with the button "See all" to expand the box to see the rest of the reviews. However, I noticed that every time I try to submit a review, the last review in the first 3 reviews didn't show up in the rest of the reviews shown upon expansion. I tried a variety of solutions but couldn't solve it.

Here's my working demo: http://immense-beach-76879.herokuapp.com/

Here's my github repo: https://github.com/kikidesignnet/hotelreviews

Here is my code.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
// import '/css/style.css';


/* An example React component */
class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

    //Initialize the state in the constructor
    this.state = {
        name: "",
        reviews: [],
        otherReviews: [],
        open: false
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    this.renderReviews = this.renderReviews.bind(this);
    this.toggleReviews = this.toggleReviews.bind(this);
    // this.addReviews = this.addReviews.bind(this);
  }
  // handle change
handleChange(e) {
    this.setState({
        name: e.target.value
    });
    console.log('onChange', this.state.name);
}

handleSubmit(e) {
    // stop browser's default behaviour of reloading on form submit
    e.preventDefault();
    axios
        .post('/reviews', {
            name: this.state.name
        })
        .then(response => {
            console.log('from handle submit', response);
            // set state
            this.setState({
                reviews: [response.data, ...this.state.reviews].slice(0,3),
                name: "",
                otherReviews: [response.data, ...this.state.reviews].slice(3).concat([...this.state.otherReviews])
            });
        });
}

renderReviews() {
    return this.state.reviews.map(review => (
        <div key={review.id} className="media innercard">
            <div className="media-body">
                <div className="profile_box">
                    <div className="profile_img">
                    <img src="/images/profilepic.png" alt="" />
                    </div>
                    <div className="profile_data">
                        <h3>{review.user.name}</h3>
                    <span className="text-muted">
                            {this.convertTime(review.updated_at)}
                    </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <p>{review.name}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    ));
}
//get all the reviews from backend
getReviews(){
    axios.get('/reviews').then(response => this.setState({
        reviews: [...response.data.reviews].slice(0,3),
        otherReviews: [...response.data.reviews].slice(3)
    }));
}


toggleReviews() {
    this.setState({open: !this.state.open});
}    

//lifecycle method
componentDidMount(){
    this.getReviews();
}


render() {
    return (
        <div className="container">
            <div className="row justify-content-center">
                <div className="col-md-8">
                    <div className="review_card">
                        <div className="card-body">
                            <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} className="comment_form">
                                <div className="form-group">
                                    <i className="fas fa-comment-dots"></i>
                                    <input
                                        onChange={this.handleChange}
                                        value = {this.state.name}
                                        className="form-control"
                                        placeholder="Comment"
                                        required
                                    />
                                </div>
                                <div className="btn_align">
                                <button type="submit" className="btn red_btn">
                                    Submit
                                </button>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                            <div className="reviews_list">
                                <div className="review_header">
                                <h1>Reviews</h1>
                                <button className="toggle_btn" onClick={this.toggleReviews}>{this.state.open ? 'Hide reviews' : 'See all'}</button>
                                </div>
                                {this.renderReviews()}
                                {this.state.open && this.state.otherReviews.map(review =>(
                                    <div key={review.id} className="media innercard">
                                        <div className="media-body">
                                            <div className="profile_box">
                                                <div className="profile_img">
                                                <img src="/images/profilepic.png" alt="" />
                                                </div>
                                                <div className="profile_data">
                                                    <h3>{review.user.name}</h3>
                                                <span className="text-muted">
                                                        {this.convertTime(review.updated_at)}
                                                </span>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <p>{review.name}</p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    ))}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
    }
}

export default App;
```

This is the code that I'm trying to edit to show the submitted review in the box.

```
handleSubmit(e) {
        // stop browser's default behaviour of reloading on form submit
        e.preventDefault();
        axios
            .post('/reviews', {
                name: this.state.name
            })
            .then(response => {
                console.log('from handle submit', response);
                // set state
                this.setState({
                    reviews: [response.data, ...this.state.reviews].slice(0,3),
                    name: "",
                    otherReviews: [response.data, ...this.state.reviews].slice(3).concat([...this.state.otherReviews])
                });
            });
    }
```

How do I solve this and what am I doing it wrong?

Comment: The demo requires login

Comment: try this:  otherReviews: [response.data, ...this.state.reviews].concat([...this.state.otherReviews])   if it doens`t work is because you are setting state of reviews (slicing to 3) before updating other reviews

Comment: It seems the code you posted here is different from the one used in the demo: https://github.com/kikidesignnet/hotelreviews/blob/master/resources/js/components/App.js#L44

Comment: @ischenkodv, Yes because I'm currently working on the code before pushing them to the demo and the github

Comment: @Rodrigo, Thanks! I got it to work by adding this code: `[...this.state.reviews].slice(2).concat([...this.state.otherReviews])`

Comment: Just an advice, i thinks theres no need to have 2 arrays of reviews, you can store all reviews in 1 array.Then you create a variable isShowingAll set to false , if the button `see all` is clicked you turn it to true, this way you can control if you are showing only 3 or the whole list. its easier to manipulate just one array.

Comment: @Rodrigo...I kinda don't understand what you mean unless you put it down in code. I did a search about that before to see how I can do that but I didn't find any solution online so I had to make 2 arrays instead...